# MYSQL design about clients

Tags: java, mysql

I've been learning mysql for a couple weeks because I need to make a JAVA program where I can add clients to a table(JTable).
The structure on mysql to do that is quite simple, just make a table with name, phone, address, etc.
The thing is.. those clients buy products, and I need to put that on the mysql aswell. So imagine I have clients, and each client buy things right?
How do I manage that? I've been thinking on an idea but I don't know if it is the best one:
-each client has an unique ID, when I add on the products table, I just grab the ID from the client and put it on the product.. So if the client ID.1 buys 5 products, I would have on porduct table:

- id - 1 ; product - shampoo
- id - 1 ; product - computer
- id - 1 ; product - trashcan

and when I want to put on a table(JTable) I just grab the products by the ID, but is it really a good way of doing it?

I hope you understand my question, what I need and want, and thank you for your time in helping me!
Also sorry if I made any english mistake.

**EDIT:** My idea is a two tables mysql structure, the rest it's explained

**EDIT2:** I'm sorry I should have explained better, the thing is, the "product" can't be initiated, it will be created at the time. Imagine you have an entreprise which do a little bit of everything such as: Sell a home, build a home, build a kitchen, sell yogurts, (an entreprise which find clients to your client and earn a % money, a comission I would say). SO there is no way I could know what our client want us to do.

Comment: You have to do another table for product and put a foreign key inside that points to the client primary key

Comment: It's actually a simple and good way of doing it, no worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have a products table - with a PRODUCT_ID column and all the other details about the product (PRICE, etc) and a seperate clients table (With CLIENT_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, etc.).
And then you can have a transaction table, linking a product to a client who purchased it. With a TRANSACTION_ID, CLIENT_ID and PRODUCT_ID (maybe date, price paid, etc).
You enter purchases into this table, and use it together with the other tables to display data in the JTable by joining the tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you read my EDIT2 note? I'm sorry for any mistake

Comment: I did read EDIT2, but it doesn't change my answer. All it means is that your applications must provide a means to updating the products table. After a new product has been added, it will have an auto generated id, or better, a uuid, and be identified by that.

Answer (score 0):

So you start with 2 tables - clients and products.

You cannot put client_id on product - because more than one client will buy the same product (hopefully).

So this is a many to many relationship between client and product tables - a client can buy many products and a product can be bought by many clients. So you need a relationship table - to store client_id and product_id combination.

We can call this relationship table "cart" (shopping cart that you see in shops). Each client will have their own cart - and they will put products in the cart. This cart table will have two columns client_id and product_id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you read my EDIT2 note? I'm sorry for any mistake

Comment: Doesn't matter if product table has data or not. You would still need the table. It would be odd - but you can always populate the product table when you know what product your customers want.